# ASP.NET Dynamic Control Generation for Multiple Types of Controls

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, textbox, postback

I want to create dynamic fields. I googled couple of examples and got them working, however the problem in all of those examples is that they are dealing with one type of Control, in most cases its TextBox.

What I want is the ability to create and render back different UIControls such as TextBox, DropDownList, Button etc.

Optional:
I found one example, which I modified and it rendered TextBox and DropDownList dynamically. However due to the Type, I had to process TextBox and DropDownList in seperate loops, which resulted in a UI where all TextBox controls are rendered first and then all the DropDownList controls are rendered (so basically the order is not preserved).

**UPDATE: Added source code.**
The .ASPX.CS file:

```
    public partial class DynamicFields : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static int intControlCountTXB = 0;
    static int intControlCountDDL = 0;
    static int intControlCount = 0;
    private Control[] arrControls;
    private DropDownList[] arrDDL;
    private TextBox[] arrTXB;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }![enter image description here][1]

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control myControl = GetPostBackControl(this.Page);

        if ((myControl != null))
        {
            if ((myControl.ClientID.ToString() == "btnAddTextBox"))
            {
                intControlCountTXB = intControlCountTXB + 1;
                intControlCount++;

            }

            if ((myControl.ClientID.ToString() == "btnAddDDL"))
            {
                intControlCountDDL = intControlCountDDL + 1;
                intControlCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        int i;
        TextBox txbTarget;
        DropDownList ddlTarget;
        arrDDL = new DropDownList[intControlCountDDL];
        arrTXB = new TextBox[intControlCountTXB];


        for (i = 0; i < intControlCountDDL; i += 1)
        {
            ddlTarget = new DropDownList();
            ddlTarget.ID = "DDL" + i.ToString();

            ddlTarget.Items.Add("A");
            ddlTarget.Items.Add("B");
            ddlTarget.Items.Add("C");
            ddlTarget.Items.Add("D");

            myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ddlTarget);
            arrDDL[i] = ddlTarget;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < intControlCountTXB; i += 1)
        {
            txbTarget = new TextBox();
            txbTarget.ID = "TXB" + i.ToString();

            myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(txbTarget);
            arrTXB[i] = txbTarget;

        }

    }




    protected void btnAddTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Handled in preInit due to event sequencing.
    }

    protected void btnAddDDL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Handled in preInit due to event sequencing.            
    }


    public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page thePage)
    {
        Control myControl = null;
        string ctrlName = thePage.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if (((ctrlName != null) & (ctrlName != string.Empty)))
        {
            myControl = thePage.FindControl(ctrlName);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string Item in thePage.Request.Form)
            {
                Control c = thePage.FindControl(Item);
                if (((c) is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button))
                {
                    myControl = c;
                }
            }

        }
        return myControl;
    }

}
```

And the .ASPX File:

```
    <form runat="server" id="frmMaster">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <a id="top" name="top"></a>


    <ajax:UpdateProgress id="uprMain" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upMain" DisplayAfter="0">
        <progresstemplate>        
            <div id="spnLoading" class="LoadingDiv">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="LoadingTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%" height="100%" class="LoadingTableCell">
                            <img src="images/icon_loading.gif">&nbsp;Please Wait...
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </progresstemplate>
    </ajax:UpdateProgress> 


    <div id="globalWrapper">
        <div id="contentstart">

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="hid" runat="server" />
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddTextBox" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>                    
            </asp:UpdatePanel>                            

            <asp:Button ID="btnAddTextBox" runat="server"  Text="Add TextBox" OnClick="btnAddTextBox_Click" />

            <asp:Button ID="btnAddDDL" runat="server"  Text="Add DDL" OnClick="btnAddDDL_Click" />

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="MyLabel"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>              

        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="divFooter" class="Footer" runat="server" visible="true">
        <br />
        Copyright © 2012. All rights reserved.
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>        
</form>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see your example. Where are you storing the controls? Are you sure that you cannot use an UserControl instead(f.e. swap `Visibility` of controls in it) or any builtin [DataBound control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) instead?

Comment: Or even group them in an `ASP:Panel` and toggle `Visibility` as needed? Dynamic controls aren't for the faint of heart, they have lots of pitfalls that one needs to be extremely careful about, so an alternate route is generally advised.

Comment: Tim, Please have a look at the source code

Comment: RLB.USA, I would agree generally. But I want to implement this framework which would be implementing my future requirements, it has to be atleast that generic. Toggling visibility would be clumsy for such a generic implementation. I can invest time today to save some tomorrow.

Comment: Tim, are you recommending that I should develop basic UserControls for each UIControl element? For instance TextBoxUC, DropDownListUC and ButtonUC?

Comment: Added screenshot of how the UI is rendered. Also cleaned up the code for you to understand it quicker.